# Problemas al instalar MinGW en Windows

Tags: windows, gcc

Intente instalar minGW en mi windows 10, pero me salen errores y no se que se deben, mi internet funciona bien. 
Dejo los detalles por si alguien sepa como solucionar

```
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-gui.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-lic.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-dll.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-xml.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-gui.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-lic.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-dll.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-xml.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** setup: unable to continue
```

Comment: porque no utilizas `gcc` desde [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)? solo abre una terminal y escribe `wsl --install`

Answer (score 0):

Si no te los descarga los complementos hazlo tu mismo en los errores te dejan los links de descarga solo accede a ellos por ejemplo uno que te aparece: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download

Comment: Entonces creo la carpeta con los archivos y vuelvo a ejecutar el instalador?